# Sprite appearing in top right corner of the screen in LIBGDX

Tags: libgdx, screen

I am working on a game using LIBGDX. I am following tutorial from this  . Everything works perfectly fine but my output sprite is at the top right corner of the screen. I am trying to center it around but I am not able to ! I even adjusted the camera but I failed. 
   This is my part of screen code,

```
public PlayScreen(MyGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    this.gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
    this.gamePort = new FitViewport(MyX.V_WIDTH / MyXGame.PPM, MyX.V_HEIGHT / MyXGame.PPM, gamecam);
    this.hud = new HudClass(game.batch);

    loader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = loader.load("tiledmap.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / MyJungleGame.PPM); 
    gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0); 
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true); 
    b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    creator = new B2WorldCreator(this);
    gamehero = new Hero(this);
    world.setContactListener(new WorldContactListener());
    items = new Array<Item>(); //initializing things
    itemsToSpawn = new LinkedBlockingQueue<ItemDef>();
}
```

My render method,

```
public void render(float delta) {
    this.update(delta);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderer.render(); 
    b2dr.render(world, gamecam.combined); 
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(this.gamecam.combined);                
    game.batch.begin();
    gamehero.draw(game.batch); 

    for (Goomba enemy : creator.getGoombas()) 
        enemy.draw(game.batch);

    for(Item item :items)
        item.draw(game.batch);

    game.batch.end();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
    hud.stage.draw();
}
```

I have attached the screen shot of the output . [image: output]

To my knowledge, problem lies in setting up the camera in playscreen. But I don't know how to resolve it. Please help I am new to LIBGDX. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera

This is the best help that I can give to you. Hope that it helps. Also, I would encourage you to write and design better you code, it is somehow a little bit hard to read.

Cheers.